# Gitlab CI and Go modules

Tags: go, gitlab, go-modules

I have a Go project and I want write a Gitlab CI file my project but I see error loading module requirements. This is my gitlab CI file:

```
stages:
  - compile
build:
  stage: compile
  image: golang:1.12
  script:
    - go build -o binary
```

```
error :
Running with gitlab-runner 11.8.0 (4745a6f3)
  on Runner #6 e0e0c446
Using Docker executor with image golang:1.12 ...
Pulling docker image golang:1.12 ...
Using docker image sha256:be63d15101cb68aea1841b45201b08a1a486c1a60a029bbf0ddb284ab646b0b7 for golang:1.12 ...
Running on runner-e0e0c446-project-753-concurrent-0 via runner-01.tool.afra.snapp.infra...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/Alsopa/echo-training'...
Checking out ab3994cc as develop...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ go build -o binary
go: finding github.com/labstack/gommon v0.2.9
go: finding github.com/labstack/echo v3.3.10+incompatible
go: finding github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.4.1
go: google.golang.org/appengine@v1.6.1: unrecognized import path "google.golang.org/appengine" (parse https://google.golang.org/appengine?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
go: error loading module requirements
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you upload the last go.sum file. Just before uploading to master for the ci execution run `go get`, upload to master and run the ci.

Answer (score 0):

The primary error seems to be:

```
go: google.golang.org/appengine@v1.6.1: unrecognized import path
 "google.golang.org/appengine" (parse 
 https://google.golang.org/appengine?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

I would try running `go get -v google.golang.org/appengine` and `curl -v https://google.golang.org/appengine?go-get=1` from within your CI environment to see what they show.

This is what I get for `go get -v google.golang.org/appengine`:

```
$ go get -v google.golang.org/appengine
Fetching https://google.golang.org/appengine?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://google.golang.org/appengine?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "google.golang.org/appengine": found meta tag
 get.metaImport{Prefix:"google.golang.org/appengine",
 VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/golang/appengine"}
 at https://google.golang.org/appengine?go-get=1
```

Perhaps you have some network connectivity, firewall, or HTTP proxy issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should download modules before compilation. Assuming your project already has go modules files `go.mod` and `go.sum` try to update `.gitlab-ci.yml` this way

```
build:
  stage: compile
  image: golang:1.13
  script:
    - go get -d -v
    - go build -o binary
```